# re-sizing graphic images - png - text

Tags: image-processing, png

When you re-size a png image (programatically or via photoshop), does the quality of the image deteriorate?  Specifically does text becomeblurry.

Is it better to re-size the text in the original photoshop psd image and generate a new png, or will reducing a png give the same results.

Comment: It is usually possible to resize in a way that text remains legible. Have you tried doing the comparison in Photoshop?

Comment: I have approx 1000X1000px images provided by design company and user wants 80X80px.  Results look poor to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Resizing any raster image will make its quality less than the original image. It is better to create it at the resolution desired.

Note that resizing the text in photoshop means vector (re)rendering at the correct resolution/size, so you will get perfect quality.

Comment: "...resizing the text in photoshop means vector..." ... if you are dealing with a photoshop Text object that has not been yet rasterized, of course.

Comment: Agreed, that is what I meant. Thanks @leonbloy